# Searching not happening in grocery crud

Tags: php, codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

In grocery crud, searching is not happening for related tables.

Searching is only happening for that table fields.

```
function index()  { 
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();
    $crud->set_theme('flexigrid');
    $crud->set_table('table_name');
    $crud->display_as('id','Name');
    $crud->callback_column('id', array($this, 'changeName'));
    $output = $crud->render();
}
```

---

```
function changeName($value, $row)  {
    $new = $this->db->select('name')->where('another_table.id', $row->id)->get('another_table')->result();
    if(!empty($new)){
        return $new[0]->name;
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Here search is not happening for name.

Any one have solution for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how many results are retuned in your `changeName` query? How many results do you expect returned?

Comment: Hai ekims, changeName is only for change id to respective names. After this changing we can't search these names... Only we can search the respective table fields... My requirement is to search these names in crud datagrid.

Answer (score 2):

Hi @DelvinPaul: I hope your problem is solved. Just in case if its not solved, try debugging your query inside `changeName` using

```
log_message('info','Query: '.$this->db->last_query());
log_message('info','Result Returned: '.print_r($new,true));
```

put these statements after the following line in your changeName function:

```
$new = $this->db->select('name')->where('another_table.id', $row->id)->get('another_table')->result();
```

And don't forget to change `$config['log_threshold'] = 3;` in your config file. After debugging, please update your question for more clarity so that we can answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$crud->set_theme('datatables');
```

Instead of

```
$crud->set_theme('flexigrid');
```

and u will have it working . This problem is only with flexgrid theme.

Comment: Hows that possible man datables theme is using Jquery datatables and if your grid is populating properly it must be searcahble..